# Is it possible for a teams messaging extension to return a plaintext response instead of a card?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to create a messaging extension for Teams based on the v4 bot SDK that searches a knowledge base and provides suggested responses that can be placed into a chat.  The search works, and I can select a card to put into the chat, but I'd like to strip out the formatting and just return a block of text to the chat (i.e. I don't want anyone else in the chat to see that the response came from an extension).  I'm able to specify a list of cards in my search results, and I tried setting the cardAction property of my heroCard search result result to "messageBack", but this still puts a full card into the team chat.  I tried mocking up something simple that just has a static response to see if I could get this working:

```
        MessagingExtensionResult composeExtensionResult = new MessagingExtensionResult
        {
            Type = "result",
            AttachmentLayout = "list",
            Attachments = new List<MessagingExtensionAttachment>(),
        };

        HeroCard h = new HeroCard()
        {                
            Title="Intro",
            Text="Hello, my name is Inigo Montoya, you killed my father, prepare to die.",                 
            Tap=new CardAction()
            {
                Type= "messageBack",
                DisplayText="send message",
                Text="111",
            },
        };
        composeExtensionResult.Attachments.Add(h.ToAttachment().ToMessagingExtensionAttachment());
```

Any idea whether there's a way to get a plain text response, or do bot responses always come back attributed to the bot?

Comment: Would this be for a v3 or v4 bot? The GitHub repo for this (https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams) states it is only for v3 at this time. There is no v4 offering yet.

Comment: Great point-this is v4, but I grabbed the 4.0.0-beta1 package from Nuget.  Should have stated that in the original post.

Answer (score 2):

So it appears that the above example works after all (sort of). I tried changing the card to format like this:

```
        HeroCard h = new HeroCard()
        {                
            Text="Hello, my name is Inigo Montoya, you killed my father, prepare to die.",
        };
```

Which puts in a card-like response when I use the compose extension:
[image: image of compose extension card]

If I look at this same post as another user though, I get this:
[image: Remote user view of card]
So it appears that this is intentional, but perhaps not documented as well as it could be.  It is worth noting that the contents of the card will still be sent, just not the overall compose extension title and image.

Comment: Were there any updates you found to this as of Nov 2020?  We are also trying to send a normal text message using a message extension but running into this hurdle.